# Power in finite field

Tags: finite-fields

Does the following statement hold true for any finite field?

$$a^p\equiv a     \qquad(\mathbb{Z_p})$$

I have tought at it this way: all numbers in $\mathbb{Z_p}$ are $\in \{0,\mathbb{Z_p}\}$ and $p*a< a^p< p^p=p\iff a< a^p< p$

I still miss something

Comment: What does $\leq$ mean in a finite field??

Comment: And do you specifically mean fields of prime order?

Comment: Also, what is $z$ supposed to be here?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom 
I mean finite field over the primes.
Edited $z$ was meant to be $p$

Comment: Many symptomatic (also common and related) syntactic confusions visible here. You can order (using $<$) integers, but it does not make sense to say that one element of the field $\Bbb{Z}_p$ would be bigger than another. This is because those elements are really residue classes modulo $p$. Often we conveniently abuse notation and denote a residue class with a representative. This is confusing in the beginning, but becomes second nature after a while. So 
$$\Bbb{Z}_p=\{\overline{0},\overline{1},\overline{2},\ldots,\overline{p-1}\}.$$
Integers can be congruent to each other modulo $p$, but...

Comment: (cont'd) elements of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ are equal. So
$$2^5=32\equiv2\pmod{5}$$ and $$7\equiv2\pmod5,$$ but $$\overline{2}^5=\overline{2}$$ and
$$\overline{7}=\overline{2}$$ in the field $\Bbb{Z}_5$. For all the elements $a\in\Bbb{Z}_p$ we have $a^p=a$. For all the integers $n$ we have $\overline{n}^p=\overline{n}$ in $\Bbb{Z}_p$ and also $n^p\equiv n\pmod p$. Yeah, those overlines become a pain after a while, but I don't think you have reached that state yet  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each element $a$ of a field $F$ of *cardinality* $q$ is a root of 
$$X^q -X,$$ 
so $a^q = a$  in $F$.

Note though that you need the cardinality of the field (not its characteristic), so the $q$ might not be a prime number.

Comment: $X^q-X=0 \iff a^q-a=0$?

Comment: Yes, $a$ is a root of $X^q-X$ iff $a^q-a = 0$. (But, $X^q-X$ is not the $0$ polynomial.)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that this is true for any field of prime order is known as [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).  For other finite fields, however, this need not hold.